# How to use system audio output to draw spectrum in my C# application

Tags: c#, audio, system-sounds

I want to display the spectrum of output audio of my windows C# application. Currently i am using NAudio Library to calculate information through PCM data of input file. But it seems that this process is taking a lot of time and processing in older systems configurations. So i was wondering if i can use the windows audio output data to do so. I meant this.

[image]

As you can see windows is generating green bar of current sound output. And it does recognize multiple outputs in MIXER. So is there any way to get this data and use in my application to escape extra calculation? And i haven't posted any code or my work as i am not sure how to do that and if that is even possible so kindly bear with me.

Thank. You.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Stereomix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN8Lp.png) which echos the computer's output as an input device. Listening to this input will be the probably easiest way to detect sounds playing. Also take a look at [Loopback Recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thanks for replying. But I dont to retake the output as input. I just want the spectrum, for that i guess i want the data windows is using to generate the visualizer.

Comment: I don't think that listening to the data will use too much resources. I suspect that is what the windows dialog is doing itself. And because I doubt that you could find an API for this, I ended up suggesting what I suggested.